# OnClick the function behind it runs but values are not displayed in the form (webForms)

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, postback, asp

I am not sure why this is happening it is working alright on my other form which have almost similar code.

Button

```
 <td>                         
<asp:Button Text="Proceed"  AutoPostBack="true"   runat="server" ID="btnGet" OnClick="btnGet_Click" />
</td>
```

Form fields

```
  <table> 
                <tr >
                        <td visible="false" runat="server" ID="hideTo1"  style="min-width: 180px;" >
                                <label>To</label>
                            </td>
                        <td visible="false" runat="server" ID="hideTo2" style="width: 400px;">
                            
                                <SharePoint:DateTimeControl LocaleId="2057" ID="dtpTo" runat="server"  DatePickerFrameUrl="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_layouts/15/iframe.aspx %>"  />
                                <%--<span class="Mandatory">*</span>--%>
                          </td>
                    </tr>
                   
                    <tr>
                        <td style="min-width: 180px;" >
                                <label>Time In</label>
                            </td>
                
                        <td style="min-width: 400px;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTimeIn" runat="server"  TextMode="Time"></asp:TextBox>
                         </td>
                        <td style="min-width: 180px;">
                                <label>Time Out</label>
                            </td>
                
                        <td style="min-width: 400px;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTimeOut" runat="server"  TextMode="Time"></asp:TextBox>     
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="min-width: 180px;">
                                <label>Reason</label><span class="Mandatory">*</span>
                            </td>
                        <td style="min-width: 400px;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtReason" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Reason") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

OnClick Function where values are being set

```
 txtReason.Text = IsNull(item["Reason"]);
 txtTimeIn.Text = IsNull(item["IN"]);
 txtTimeOut.Text = IsNull(item["Out"]);
 txtTimeIn.Enabled = false;
 txtTimeOut.Enabled = false;
 txtReason.Enabled = false;
 fupAttachment.Enabled = false;
 btnSave.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Can you please check if code in page load. it seems your form is resetting from there only

Comment: page load is running then onclick function runs but on browser neither page is reloaded nor the values are set

Comment: each time you click on button page load will run?

Comment: yes it is running but i dont want it to run

Comment: well it really doesnt matter if it loads or not. what matters is that onclick function runs afterwards but does not display values on the form.

Comment: To avoid page load/refresh on button click, try adding this to your button element: `type="button"`

Comment: I have add type="button"  but the results are same.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved by taking out the proceed button from my updatepanel. I am not sure why exactly it was not working properly but I found the solution
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881470/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception-an-unknown-error-occurred-w)